# Ajax / Django .append() sends POST request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I am creating a webpage where the user submits a form, which then creates an object in Django (using Ajax, so the page doesn't refresh). This works fine when I don't include the .append() method in the successful response section.

However, when I try to add a new semantic-ui card after the successful request, the page refreshes and submits the form via a normal POST request to Django, instead of through Ajax so the page doesn't refresh. Do you know why that might be?

```
$('#post-form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("form submitted!")  
    create_post();
});

function create_post() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "/create_post/", // the endpoint
        type : "POST", // http method
        data : { post : $('#post').val() }, // data sent with the post request

        // handle a successful response
        success : function(json) {
            $('#post').val(''); // remove the value from the input
            console.log(json); // log the returned json to the console

            // this causes the page to refresh and the form to POST
            $('#add-card').append("
                <div class='ui card'>
                    <div class='content'>
                        <div class='description'>
                            Test Test test
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ");


            console.log("success"); 
        },


    });
};
```

And the HTML page:

```
    <div class="ui four cards" id="add-card">
        <div id="add-card">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting any errors in the console?

You should not have two elements on the page with the same id, `add-card`

The string you are passing in to `append` may be causing a syntax error. Strings can't carry over to the next line like that in javascript. Either close the strings on each line and concat them with `+`, or try putting a `\` at the end of each line that does not terminate the string.

**A.** concatenate the strings together:

```
$('#add-card').append(
    "<div class='ui card'>"+
    "    <div class='content'>"+
    "        <div class='description'>"+
    "            Test Test test"+
    "        </div>"+
    "    </div>"+
    "</div>"
);
```

or **B.** end lines with slashes if the string continues on the next line. (looks better but may lead to errors in the future if you edit this content):

```
$('#add-card').append("\
    <div class='ui card'>\
        <div class='content'>\
            <div class='description'>\
                Test Test test\
            </div>\
        </div>\
    </div>\
");
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! For future reference, are javascript errors supposed to be printed to the console? I wasn't getting any errors, and was wondering how to catch errors?

Comment: Yes they should be, but if the page is reloading at the same time you'll lose what's in the console so you would probably miss it in this case. Of course you can always wrap things in the good old `try { ... } catch(ex) { ... }`

Comment: Also, the console experience will depend on your browser. (And some browsers won't have the `console` object defined, so watch out with `console.log()` calls if this code is going to a production environment.)

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of issues here that may be causing a problem...

1) You are appending another element with the same `id` (`#`). `id`'s should be unique, `class`s (`.`) are not.

2) In JS, you can't just have your string content on seperate lines without concatenating them, do this instead...

```
$('#add-card').append(
    '<div class="ui card">' +
    '    <div class="content">' +
    '        <div class="description">' +
    '            Test Test test' +
    '        </div>' +
    '    </div>' +
    '</div>'
);
```

Comment: watch out for the single quotes on the class names

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the wrong code for (3). The function name is correct, I just changed it in my post